Large invariant types realized in $\cal U$.
Below $\cal U$ is a monster model; $\varphi(x;y)$ a given parameter-free formula; $a\in\cal U^y$.

When is the type $p(x)$ = { $\varphi(x;fa):f\in{\rm Aut}({\cal U})$ } realized in $\cal U$? (Assuming it is finitely consistent.)

Below two easy (in a sense, trivial) cases. Any other?

$p(x)$ contains (up to equivalence) finitely many (equivalently boundedly many) formulas. Then $p(x)$ is equivalent to a formula over ${\rm acl}^{\rm eq}(\varnothing)$.

tp($a$) is isolated, say it is equivalent to the formula $\psi(y)$, then $p(x)$ is equivalent to the formula $\forall y\ [\psi(y)\rightarrow\varphi(x;y)]$.



This happens if and only if it happens for a definable reason.
Precisely: Let $\mathcal{U}\models T$ be a monster model, $\varphi(x;y)$ a formula, and $a\in \mathcal{U}^y$. Then $p(x) = \{\varphi(x;f(a))\mid f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{U})\}$ is realized in $\mathcal{U}$ if and only if there is some formula $\psi(y)\in \mathrm{tp}(a/\varnothing)$ such that $T\models \exists x\, \forall y\, (\psi(y)\to \varphi(x;y))$.
One direction is clear, since $\mathcal{U}\models \psi(f(a))$ for all $f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{U})$, so any witness to the existential quantifier in the sentence above realizes $p$.
In the other direction, suppose $b\in \mathcal{U}^x$ realizes $p$. Consider the partial type $\{\lnot \varphi(b;y)\}\cup \mathrm{tp}(a/\varnothing)$. I claim this type is inconsistent. Indeed, if $a'$ realizes it, then since $a'\models \mathrm{tp}(a/\varnothing)$, there is an automorphism $f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{U})$ such that $f(a) = a'$. Then $\mathcal{U}\models \lnot \varphi(b;f(a))$, contradicting the fact that $b$ realizes $p$.
By compactness and saturation of $\mathcal{U}$, there is some formula $\psi(y)\in \mathrm{tp}(a/\varnothing)$ such that $\lnot\varphi(b;y)\land \psi(y)$ is inconsistent. It follows that $\mathcal{U}\models \forall y\, (\psi(y)\to \varphi(b;y))$, so $T\models \exists x\, \forall y\, (\psi(y)\to \varphi(x;y))$.

For an example that doesn't fit into your two easy cases, let $T$ be the theory of the structure $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ in the language $\{+,\times,<\}$. We interpret $+$ and $<$ in the standard way on $\mathbb{R}$ and extend them so that $\infty$ is the greatest element and $a+\infty = \infty+a = a\times \infty = \infty\times a = \infty$ for all $a$.
Let $\varphi(x;y)$ be the formula $y\leq x$. Taking $\mathcal{U}\models T$ a monster model, let $a\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\mathrm{tp}(a/\varnothing)$ is not isolated (for example, take $a$ to be the image of $\pi$ under an elementary embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathcal{U}$).
Now the type $p(x) = \{f(a)\leq x\mid f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{U})\}$ is realized by $\infty$. But it contains infinitely many formulas up to equivalence, since there are infinitely many elements of the form $f(a)$ ($a$ is not algebraic over $\varnothing$) and the formulas $\{f(a)\leq x\mid f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{U})\}$ are pairwise non-equivalent.

Great, thank you.
